# Rails error: A server is already running permanent fix

Tags: ruby-on-rails, server

I know this question has already been asked, but I'd like to find a permanent fix for it.

If I run the rails server, quit it, then run it again, I get this error:

`A server is already running. Check /Users/giancarlo_benedetti/coding/test_project-1/tmp/pids/server.pid.`

My workaround so far has been to do `lsof -wni tcp:3000` , get the PID number, and then `kill -9 <PID_number>`.

Is there any permanent fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, its operating system concept that once the process is running and the user abruptly or mistakenly quitting the process in the wrong way. Actually, in the background, the process is not killed correctly, and that why when the user tries to restart the rails server then the machine says the server is already running.
So **no permanent solution** for this. When you are quitting or stopping your server then you have to use `ctr + c` and stop the server successfully.